# Can I configure fabric.io/Crashlytics to not put any code/data into the APK of one of my build flavours?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Can I configure fabric.io / Crashlytics to not put any code/data into one of my build flavours?

It seems that even if I disable it like so :

```
productFlavors {
    internal {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
    }
    external {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}
```

... fabric still adds some data into the build. If I look at classes.dex, and search for the word "fabric", I find stuff that's not there if I remove fabric from the build altogether.

( FYI: I use a wrapper class in the build flavor source directories (which is called from the Application's onCreate) to not have any code dependency on fabric in the "external" build. ==> There's no reference from my code to anything fabric in the "external" flavor. )

Comment: You can add the crashlytics dependency only in your buildvariants which use the lib, e.g.: compileInternal "com.crashlytics.dependency:1.0.0"

Comment: Sounds good, but if I change my line " compile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }" to compileInternal ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }   the build fails :(

Comment: Is there a general problem or do you still have a dependency to fabric-code in your main-source directory?

Comment: you where close :) ... The following works : configurations {
    internalDebugCompile
    internalReleaseCompile

    externalDebugCompile
    externalReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
    internalDebugCompile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    internalReleaseCompile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: ==> it's internalDebugCompile , not compileInternalDebug

Comment: Sure! My mistake. Well, its friday. internalCompile should work as well.

Comment: thanks, helped a lot ! ..ok, this seems to work. hint for anyone: run gradle with "clean" after adding these flavor-only build lines. Otherwise there will still be files from fabric in there.